# Pygame logo changes back after some time

Tags: python, pygame, screen

I am a noob in pygame and i have a problem.  Pygame logo changes after a while. I have two images. Pls help! First image is how the window should look like and the second image is my window after 20 sec. What schould i do? I never had this problem and i tried so many things but i can't do it.

```py
import pygame 
import random

# initialize idk pygame.init()

# size Width = 800 Height = 600 white = (255, 255, 255) icon = pygame.image.load('sunflower.png') player_img =
pygame.image.load('cat.png') enemy1_img = pygame.image.load('dog.png')
FPS = 120 Vel = 5

# enemy random coordinates enemy1_X = random.randint(64, 736) enemy1_Y = random.randint(50, 150)


# screen def screen_f(p_rect, e_rect):
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('dog destroyer')
icon = pygame.image.load('sunflower.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
backgroud = pygame.image.load('backg.png')
screen.blit(backgroud, (0, 0))
screen.blit(player_img, (p_rect))
screen.blit(enemy1_img, (e_rect))


# player def player_movement(key_pressed, p_rect):
if key_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    p_rect.x += Vel
if key_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    p_rect.x -= Vel
if key_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
    p_rect.y -= Vel
if key_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    p_rect.y += Vel


def borders(p_rect):
    if p_rect.x < 0:
        p_rect.x = 0
    elif p_rect.x > 735:
        p_rect.x = 735
    elif p_rect.y < 0:
        p_rect.y = 0
    elif p_rect.y > 535:
        p_rect.y = 535


# main def main():
Vel_e = 4  # enemy  velocity
player_rect = pygame.Rect(368, 500, 64, 64)
enemy_rect = pygame.Rect(enemy1_X, enemy1_Y, 64, 64)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    key_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    enemy_rect.x += Vel_e
    if enemy_rect.x >= 736:
        Vel_e = -4
        enemy_rect.y += 50
    if enemy_rect.x < 0:
        Vel_e = 4
        enemy_rect.y += 50

    borders(player_rect)
    player_movement(key_pressed, player_rect)
    screen_f(player_rect, enemy_rect)
    pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El6EA.png)
[image]

[After 20 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpGgt.png)
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your code is not clearly visible but i think i know how to fix it.

you usually want to set your screen and other important stuf right at the beginning of your file, not in a def that has to be called.

try it like this:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = ...
height = ...
fps = ...
#set any colors

#load all you pictures

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
# you would also want to set your caption and icon here so:
pygame.display.set_caption('your caption')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#all your defs

#and when its all set you go to a main loop.

#(at the bottom of your file)
main()
# and quit for if the user quits and run gets set to False
pygame.quit()
quit()
```